# Rails Outdated Gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Ok so I was adding some tests to a app using the [shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) gem and was getting an error

```
undefined method `allow_value'
```

Looking at the gem I could see this allow_value method was in a later date of the gem so time to update.

I ran a global bundle update and so far so good. But running the test again same error.

So I bundle outdated and got the following:

```
Outdated gems included in the bundle:
  * actionmailer (3.2.13 > 3.2.12)
  * actionpack (3.2.13 > 3.2.12)
  * activemodel (3.2.13 > 3.2.12)
  * activerecord (3.2.13 > 3.2.12)
  * activeresource (3.2.13 > 3.2.12)
  * activesupport (3.2.13 > 3.2.12)
  * arel (4.0.0 > 3.0.2)
  * bourne (1.4.0 > 1.1.2)
  * builder (3.2.2 > 3.0.4)
  * coffee-rails (4.0.0 > 3.2.2)
  * faye-websocket (0.6.1 > 0.4.7)
  * json (1.8.0 > 1.7.7)
  * mail (2.5.4 > 2.4.4)
  * mocha (0.14.0 > 0.10.5)
  * rack (1.5.2 > 1.4.5)
  * rails (3.2.13 > 3.2.12)
  * railties (3.2.13 > 3.2.12)
  * rdoc (4.0.1 > 3.12.2)
  * shoulda-matchers (2.1.0 > 1.4.2)
  * sprockets (2.10.0 > 2.2.2)
  * tzinfo (1.0.0 > 0.3.37)
```

I tried again with bundle update shoulda-matchers but same issue.

How do I update the gem to the latest version? and to that fact how come actionmailer etc is not updated when I run bundle update.

Hope you can advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still on 3.2.12.
So `bundle update` doesn't update your Rails version.

Make sure your `Gemfile` has

```
gem 'rail', '3.2.13'
```

and run `bundle update` again.

Some gems will still be outdated, because they are already stable for Rails 4 (i.e. `coffee-rails`). You can ignore these 'outdates'

Comment: OK much better. I should have not missed the rails version.  But the main gem I need is still out of date after doing the updates.   shoulda-matchers (2.1.0 > 1.4.2). How can you get the gem updated?

Comment: sometime it helps to update the gem manually `gem update shoulda-matchers` and then run `bundle update` again.

Comment: I already tried that martin.  running bundle update it still shows:  Using shoulda-matchers (1.4.2)

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `gem 'shoulda-matcher','~>1.4.x'` in your `Gemfile`